# Windows PaintDesktopVersion

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

I am running Win7 and wish to change the build identifier displayed when setting `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\PaintDesktopVersion` to `1`.

Is there a possibility to change this text, or to add to it (for example a name of the personal computer or a name of the user)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no API to control what gets displayed. You can hack the resources of user32.dll.mui to change the text if that's the kind of thing you like doing. Modifying the wallpaper would be a more reasonable approach in my view.

Answer (score 9):

Like David said, the string is hardcoded. The good thing is, there already exists [a great utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557) that adds text to the wallpaper.